# Can my mum set my iMessages to be received on her phone if we have separate Apple ids?

Tags: iphone, messages

Me and my mum have separate Apple ids, and I was wondering can she set it so she can see my messages? Because we used to share an Apple ID, and she could do it then. But with us now having separate one can she still do this? Thankyou to anybody who helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No she cannot see your iMessages with separate Apple ID's. Even if you are in a iCloud family.